# Blazor Startup Error: System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException: Cannot wait on monitors on this runtime

Tags: async-await, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to call an api during the blazor(client side) startup to load language translations into the ILocalizer.

At the point I try and get the .Result from the get request blazor throws the error in the title.

This can replicated by calling this method in the program.cs

```
  private static void CalApi()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees");
            string path = "ididcontent.json";
            string response = httpClient.GetStringAsync(path)?.Result;
            Console.WriteLine(response);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error getting api response: " + ex);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Avoid `.Result`, it can easily deadlock. You get this error because the mechanism is not (cannot be) supported on single-threaded webassembly. I would consider it a feature. If it could wait on a Monitor it would freeze.

```
private static async Task CalApi()
{
   ... 
   string response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(path); 
   ...
}
```

All events  and lifecycle method overrides can be `async Task` in Blazor, so you should be able to fit this in.

Comment: or in the DI setup

Comment: DI container requires sync resolution of the services. If any needs async operation, than it's impossible to do in blazor

Answer (score 4):

In Program.cs

```
 public static async Task Main(string[] args)
 {

    ......

    builder.Services.AddSingleton<SomeService>();

    var host = builder.Build();       

    ...
```

call your code here but use await

```
    var httpClient = host.Services.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>();
    string response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(path);
    ...

    var someService = host.Services.GetRequiredService<SomeService>();
    someService.SomeProperty = response;

    await host.RunAsync();
```

Comment: good suggestion. I think Ilocalizer isn't async but yeah I think you're right I might have to right my own

Answer (score 1):

This is a example best:

```
var client= new ProductServiceGrpc.ProductServiceGrpcClient(Channel);
            category =  (await client.GetCategoryAsync(new GetProductRequest() {Id = id})).Category;
```